# Given a column name how can I find which tables in database contain that column?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

- Given a column name how can I find
  which tables in database contain that
  column ?

  or alternatively
- How can I find that particular column
  exists for all tables in Database ?

**Note:** Kindly explain answers with Examples as that I get most knowledge from the answer.

**Edit:** I am using MySQL Database.

Comment: which database system are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql database system

Comment: In case of oracle meta information can be found using different oracle provided `dict`, 
http://www.alberton.info/oracle_meta_info.html is a good read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'mycolumn'
```

Comment: @nickf - sorry should have given you a chance to edit that typo in the grace period.  +1 anyway.

Comment: MySQL stores the data dictionary for the databases in the information_schema database.  In here you can see columns, tables, etc. for everything installed in your MySQL database.  There may be permission issues around this (I'm not sure).  It's also something you shouldn't update manually.  Older versions (maybe back to 4.0?) didn't have this, but it's been around for a while now, so most newer MySQL installations will have it.

Comment: ... AND TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE()

Comment: @martinclayton  I would like to add more question on how will search including its type as PK. e.g. statement that goes: where COLUMN_NAME ='<column name>' and <should be a primary key>

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database you are using. Many database systems expose a set of tables of views that contain details of the schema. For example, you can get schema information from the SYSTABLE and SYSCOLUMN views in Sybase ASA.

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server:

```
select distinct t.name
from sys.Columns c 
    inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id
where c.name = 'YOUR_COLUMNNAME'
```

Comment: Database am using is MySQL Database.